# How to stage a form in Kentico when it doesn't show up in the staging list?

Tags: kentico

Pretty much what the title says. We have a form that we've created and we want to sync it over to our staging server but it's not showing up in the staging list. At all. Do we have gremlins, is this a known issue, or is there something else amok here?

Edit: The problem might be a permissions issue but it's weird. If the user who created the form syncs it, it goes into a black hole - I understand he doesn't have permission to create forms on our staging server. When I cloned the form and synced the cloned form to staging, they both showed up.

Answer (score 1):

You can just edit the form and resave it, this will generate a staging task.

Comment: I've edited my question with more (new) information. And although your suggestion *does* work, methinks it's not quite the right way to deal with it.

Comment: @MetalPhoenix Sounds like a bug, you might want to reach out to Kentico Support on this one.

Comment: Yay! Another tree planted for me if it is. Thanks, I'll do that.